# How to add Content Security Policy to ASP.Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am in the process of building my first ASP.Net core website. The site was built using Web Forms but because they are poorly supported I decided to port it to .Net Core. Easier said than done because they basically destroyed everything that .Net developers like me relied on to make sites before.

Among these missing features is the Global.asax file which I used to set headers including the content security policy. My old Global.asax file had something like this:

```
protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders()
    {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy", "frame-src 'self' *.cloudflare.com *.abc30.com *.sinclairstoryline.com *.cnn.com *.foxnews.com *.twitch.tv *.cdninstagram.com *.fbcdn.net *.tiktok.com *.rumble.com *.rmbl.ws *.itemfix.com *.leakreality.com *.leakedreality.com *.reddit.com *.twitter.com *.dailymail.co.uk *.liveleak.com *.desmoinesregister.com *.kgw.com *.dailymotion.com *.bitchute.com *.metacafe.com *.vimeo.com *.nbcbayarea.com *.anvato.net *.abc30.com *.thv11.com *.youtube.com *.youtu.be *.google.com *.googlesyndication.com *.doubleclick.net *.jquery.net *.facebook.com *.bootstrapcdn.com *.cloudfront.net *.amazon.com *.googleapis.com *.shareaholic.net *.google-analytics.com *.viglink.com *.doubleclick.net *.tpc.googlesyndication.com *.cm.g.doubleclick.net *.pagead2.googlesyndication.com *.googleads.g.doubleclick.net *.accounts.google.com; upgrade-insecure-requests");
    }
```

How do I replicate that functionality in a .Net Core website? The ideal solution would be to add a line to the Startup.cs file or some other configuration file specifying these headers for the entire site.

I need this because the development site already accepts user submissions and some users have used a video embedding feature to frame HTML pages instead. I figure either specify a frame-src header to restrict frame rendering to whitelisted video sharing sites or alter the form inputs to disallow non-whitelisted sites.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you could try to use [asp.net core middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to achieve this requirement.

The code like below:

This is a middleware is added to the pipeline that adds a Content-Security-Policy header to every response.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy", "xxxxx");
        await next();
    });

    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
    });
}
```